# Parking Tickets\Citations (impersonified) data for USA cities

Tags: data-request, crime, parking

i've been trying to find data on Parking Tickets/Citations for US cities.
but it looks like it's really a rare occurrence for just a couple of cities like NY, Baltimore and Toronto

My search was inspired by this article 
http://iquantny.tumblr.com/post/76937212765/using-open-data-to-predict-when-you-might-get-your

i even tried calling a couple of US cities but they were quite surprised to hear such a request.

**Bottomline, does anyone know any other US cities to open the data on   parking violations?**

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.ted.com/talks/ben_wellington_how_we_found_the_worst_place_to_park_in_new_york_city_using_big_data